# How do I highlight/select neighbours of neighbours in D3 force layout?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have used this to help with highlighting neighour nodes:

http://jsfiddle.net/simonraper/jz2AU/light/

```
var toggle = 0;//Toggle stores whether the highlighting is on
var linkedByIndex = {};//Create an array logging what is connected to what

for (i = 0; i < network.network.data.nodes.length; i++) //-populate the array
{
    linkedByIndex[i + "," + i] = 1;
};
network.network.data.edges.forEach(function (d) //-checks what nodes are related in array
{
    linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
});
//-------------------------check if nodes are linked
function neighboring(a, b) //This function looks up whether a pair are neighbours
{
    return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index];
}
//-------------------------finds out connected nodes, keeps their styles but changes the opacity of every other
function connectedNodes() {
//Reduce the opacity of all but the neighbouring nodes
d = d3.select(this).node().__data__;
    if (toggle == 0) { 

        // nodes.classed("highlighted", function (o) {
            // return neighboring(d, o) | neighboring(o, d) ? true : false;
        // });      

        nodes.style("opacity", function (o) {
            return neighboring(d, o) | neighboring(o, d) ? 1 : 0.1;
        });
        links.style("opacity", function (o) {
            return d.index==o.source.index | d.index==o.target.index ? 1 : 0.1;
        });
        //Reduce the op
        toggle = 1;
    } else {
        //Put them back to opacity=1
        nodes.style("opacity", 1);
        links.style("opacity", 1);
        nodes.classed("highlighted", false);
        toggle = 0;
    }
}
```

What this does is when double clicking on a node, that selected node and its neighbours keep its opacity whilst all the others lower their opacity.

Now when I double click on one of the children of the first selected node, the whole selection goes away (the opacity of all nodes is 1).

What I wish to have, is that when I double click on one of the children nodes, the selection doesnt go away, the related nodes of that child node now become 'highlighted'.

Doing this will help guide me through the force directed graph easily, especially with much data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been trying for around an hour for this and its a simple change to the code

Change both toggles to - toggle=0;

That way when selecting a node it doesn't clear the selection it just highlights the neighbours